# Не могу запустить код с примера ghost4j, вылетает NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, intellij-idea, исключения

Нужен был алгоритм перегоняющий *pdf* в картинку.

Взял его [отсюда](http://www.ghost4j.org/highlevelapisamples.html). Поставил их библиотеки, подключил в *Idea*. Скопипастил код.

Код:

```
package com.pdf.parser;

import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.image.RenderedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths; 
import java.util.List;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

import org.ghost4j.analyzer.AnalysisItem;
import org.ghost4j.analyzer.FontAnalyzer;
import org.ghost4j.document.PDFDocument;
import org.ghost4j.renderer.SimpleRenderer;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            // load PDF document
            PDFDocument document = new PDFDocument();
            document.load(new File("C:\\path\\to\\myfile.pdf"));

            // create renderer
            SimpleRenderer renderer = new SimpleRenderer();

            // set resolution (in DPI)
            renderer.setResolution(300);

            // render
            List<Image> images = renderer.render(document);

            // write images to files to disk as PNG
            try {
                for (int i = 0; i < images.size(); i++) {
                    ImageIO.write((RenderedImage) images.get(i), "png",
                                  new File((i + 1) + ".png"));
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("ERROR: " + e.getMessage());
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("ERROR: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Вылетает с проблемами:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/lowagie/text/pdf/PdfTemplate
    at com.pdf.parser.Solution.main(Solution.java:33)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfTemplate
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 6 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас не хватает в CLASS_PATH JAR-файла com.lowagie.itext. Взять можно, например, в [Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails|com.lowagie|itext|2.1.7|jar). Хотя вообще в самом [ghost4j](http://www.ghost4j.org/downloads.html) в архиве в папке lib есть все необходимые jar-файлы. Просто добавьте их в CLASS_PATH.

Comment: можно поподробнее, не совсем понимаю что надо сделать, впервые работаю со сторонней библиотекой.

Comment: @ВадимПотапов, а как вы сам ghost4j-то подключить смогли? Как вы вообще запускаете пример?

Comment: он в project structure-> libraries подключен. Пример запускаю в обыкновенном idea проекте, правой кнопкой по классу и Run )

Comment: Ну вот туда же (в project structure -> libraries) добавьте все остальные jar-файлы из архива ghost4j.

Comment: нуу подключил вообще всё что с ним шло, теперь он
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'gsdll64': Íå íàéäåí óêàçàííûé ìîäóëü.

Comment: нашёл решение, добавил gsdll64.dll в system 32

Comment: @ВадимПотапов, там скорее всего можно прикрепить DLL прямо в IDEA к Jar-файлу. Но это по факту отдельный вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

Вам в самом проекте надо нажать кнопку *F4* и зайти в *modules* и там нажать на *dependencies* и подключить вашу библиотеку.  Если проект на мавене то можете таким же образом или с официального [сайта](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.lowagie/itext/2.1.7) подключить библиотеку

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
    <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.7</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: кнопка F4 в IDEA ничего не делает. В project structure, modules в dependencies все библиотеки лежат.

Comment: у вас мавенский проект? попробуйте удалить в репозиториях это и пересобрать мавен

Comment: после добавления всех библиотек кинул ещё gsdll64.dll в system32 и всё пошло